# Conditional variance when there is uncertainity about the distribution of condition

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, variance

Assume that $X \sim N(0,\sigma_x^2)$. Y has the following form
\begin{align}
Y &=
\begin{cases}
 Y_1 \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2), & \text{w.p.} \quad \mu \\
 Y_2 \sim N(0, \sigma_2^2), & \text{w.p.} \quad (1-\mu)
 \end{cases} 
\end{align}
where $Cov(X,Y_1) =\Sigma_1$, and $Cov(X,Y_2) =\Sigma_2$. And also X and Y1, and X and Y2 are both bivariate normally distributed.

How can we calculate $V(X|Y=y)$?
Is the following idea correct?
\begin{align*}
V(X|Y=y) = \mu V(X|Y=y_1)+(1-\mu)V(X|Y=y_2)  
\end{align*}

Basically, y is realized but it might be in the from of $y_1 \in Y_1$ or $y_2 \in Y_2$.  What do you think?

Comment: I think we need more information to solve this problem: what is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y_1$ (and $X$ with $Y_2$)? We need to know the distribution of $X$ given $Y = y, Y =Y_1$ (and $Y = y, Y =Y_2$) in order to solve this question. Can we assume that it is a bivariate normal distribution? From the information that you've given so far we can't: this post gives an example where $X, Y$ are both normal and have non-zero covariance but are not bivariate normal https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/293818/proving-that-x-y-is-not-bivariate-normal

Comment: $X$ and $Y_1$, and $X$ and  $Y_2$ are both bivariate normal distribution. But when $y$ is realized it is not known whether it comes from $Y_1$ or $Y_2$. Is this information enough, @Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Conditional Variance Formula:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance#Definition)
$$\mathbb{V}(X \mid Y = y) = \mathbb{E}((X - \mathbb{E}(X\mid Y = y))^{2}\mid Y = y)$$
We need to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y)$, and we can do this using a variation of the [Law of Total Expectation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) Let $A_i$ be the event $Y = Y_i$.
$$\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y) = \int x\thinspace f_{x \mid y}dx = \int x\frac{f_{x,y}}{f_y}dx = \int x\sum_i \frac{f_{x,y,A_i}}{f_y}dx$$
$$= \int x\sum_i \frac{f_{x,y,A_i}}{f_{y,A_i}}\frac{f_{y,A_i}}{f_{y}}dx= \int x\sum_i \frac{f_{x,y,A_i}}{f_{y,A_i}}\frac{f_{y,A_i}}{f_{y}}dx = \sum_i\int x \thinspace f_{x \mid y, A_i}\mathbb{P}(A_i \mid Y = y)dx$$
$$= \sum_i \int x \thinspace f_{x \mid y, A_i}dx \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_i \mid Y = y) = \sum_i \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y, A_i)\mathbb{P}(A_i \mid Y = y).$$
So
$$\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y) = \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y, Y = Y_1) \mathbb{P}(Y = Y_1 \mid Y = y) + \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y, Y = Y_2) \mathbb{P}(Y = Y_2 \mid Y = y).$$
We can use [Bayes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) to calculate the probabilities above:
$$\mathbb{P}(Y = Y_1 \mid Y = y) = \frac{f_{Y_1}(y) \mathbb{P}(Y = Y_1)}{f_{Y_1}(y) \mathbb{P}(Y = Y_1) + f_{Y_2}(y) \mathbb{P}(Y = Y_2)}$$
where
$$f_{Y_i}(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_i^2}}e^{-y^2/2\sigma_i^2} \text{for } i = 1, 2.$$
So
$$\mathbb{P}(Y = Y_1 \mid Y = y) = \frac{1/\sigma_1 e^{-y^2/2\sigma_1^2} \mu}{1/\sigma_1 e^{-y^2/2\sigma_1^2} \mu + 1/\sigma_2 e^{-y^2/2\sigma_2^2} (1 -\mu)} = \frac{\sigma_2 \mu e^{-y^2/2\sigma_1^2}}{\sigma_2 \mu e^{-y^2/2\sigma_1^2} + \sigma_1 (1 - \mu)e^{-y^2/2\sigma_2^2}}.$$
Also
$$\mathbb{P}(Y = Y_2 \mid Y = y) = \frac{\sigma_1 (1 - \mu) e^{-y^2/2\sigma_2^2}}{\sigma_2 \mu e^{-y^2/2\sigma_1^2} + \sigma_1 (1 - \mu)e^{-y^2/2\sigma_2^2}}.$$
The conditional distribution of $X \mid Y = y, Y = Y_i$ [is given by](https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/118/)
$$X \mid Y = y, Y = Y_i \sim N\left(\mu_x + \rho_i\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_i}(y - \mu_i), \sigma_x^2 (1 - \rho_i^2) \right)$$
where $\rho_i$ is the correlation of $X$ and $Y_i$, $\mu_x = \mathbb{E}(X) = 0$ and $\mu_i = \mathbb{E}(Y_i) = 0$.

Putting this together we have
$$\mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y) = \rho_1\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_1}y \cdot p_1 + \rho_2\frac{\sigma_x}{\sigma_2}y \cdot p_2 = \mu_{x \mid y},$$
where $p_i = \mathbb{P}(Y = Y_i \mid Y = y)$.
Returning to the conditional variance formula, we now expand it, conditioning on $Y = Y_i$ again:
$$\mathbb{V}(X \mid Y = y) = \mathbb{E}((X - \mu_{x\mid y})^{2}\mid Y = y)$$
$$= \mathbb{E}((X - \mu_{x\mid y})^{2}\mid Y = y, Y = Y_1)\mathbb{P}(Y = Y_1 \mid Y = y) + \mathbb{E}((X - \mu_{x\mid y})^{2}\mid Y = y, Y = Y_2)\mathbb{P}(Y = Y_2 \mid Y = y).$$
Now $$(X - \mu_{x\mid y})^{2} = (X - \mu_{x \mid y,i} + \mu_{x \mid y,i} - \mu_{x\mid y})^{2} = (X - \mu_{x \mid y,i})^2 + 2(X - \mu_{x \mid y,i})(\mu_{x \mid y,i} - \mu_{x\mid y}) + (\mu_{x \mid y,i} - \mu_{x\mid y})^2,$$
where $\mu_{x \mid y,i} = \mathbb{E}(X \mid Y = y, Y = Y_i)$, so
$$\mathbb{E}((X - \mu_{x\mid y})^{2}\mid Y = y = Y_i) = \mathbb{E}((X - \mu_{x \mid y,i})^2 + 2(X - \mu_{x \mid y,i})(\mu_{x \mid y,i} - \mu_{x\mid y}) + (\mu_{x \mid y,i} - \mu_{x\mid y})^2\mid Y = y = Y_i)$$
$$= \sigma_x^2 (1 - \rho_i^2) + 0 + (\mu_{x \mid y,i} - \mu_{x\mid y})^2.$$
Therefore 
$$\mathbb{V}(X \mid Y = y) = \left(\sigma_x^2 (1 - \rho_1^2) + (\mu_{x \mid y,1} - \mu_{x\mid y})^2 \right)p_1 + \left(\sigma_x^2 (1 - \rho_2^2) + (\mu_{x \mid y,2} - \mu_{x\mid y})^2 \right)p_2.$$
$$ = \sigma_x^2 + \left(- \sigma_x^2 \rho_1^2 + (\mu_{x \mid y,1} - \mu_{x\mid y})^2 \right)p_1 + \left(- \sigma_x^2 \rho_2^2 + (\mu_{x \mid y,2} - \mu_{x\mid y})^2 \right)p_2.$$

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Alex, really appreciate that.